# When creating .exe with pyinstaller in Anaconda, resultant .exe fails

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller, spyder

first question here in Stackoverflow!

I'm currently making a small script that takes a list of youtube exercise videos stored in an excel and selects a few to create an exercise routine[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XInO.png).

I made the script in spyder, once it's made I used pyinstaller trough the Anaconda command prompt.

Once the folder appeared it just gives me the error shown in the image (link).

I'm not quite sure if its a pyinstaller error, or I'm making something wrong.

Also, it's a fairly simple script and the executable is bigger than 300Mb, which I believe it's a bit much...

```
import pandas as pd
import random as random

excel = pd.read_excel("Ejercicios.xlsx")

def creador_rutina(original_db):
   
    print("Dificultades disponibles: \n.-Facil = 6\n.-Normal = 10\n.-Fuerte = 20")
    dif_range = ["6","10","20"]
    dificultad = input("Indica la dificultad: ")
    
    while dificultad not in dif_range: #para asegurar que indican un valor valido
        print("Selecciona una dificultad disponible: ")
        print("Dificultades disponibles: \n.-Facil = 6\n.-Normal = 10\n.-Fuerte = 20")
        dificultad = input("Indica la dificultad: ")
   
    dificultad = int(dificultad) #los input entran como str siempre
    
    ejercicios = original_db
    global rutina
    rutina = pd.DataFrame()
    valor_rutina = 0
    
    ejercicios["Total"] = ejercicios.sum(axis=1) #agrega columna de total
      
    while valor_rutina <= dificultad:
        
        comp = dificultad - valor_rutina
        ejercicios = ejercicios[ejercicios.Total <= comp]
        ejercicios.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        
        if ejercicios.empty == True:
            
            rutina = rutina[original_db.columns]
            print(rutina)
            
            break
                
        a = random.randint(0,len(ejercicios.index)-1)
        rutina = rutina.append(ejercicios.iloc[a , :], sort=False)
        ejercicios = ejercicios.drop([a])
        valor_rutina = rutina["Total"].sum()
        
       



creador_rutina(excel)
```

Thanks for any idea you might have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done guys, after changing the recursion limit in the .spec file adding at the beginning:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

The code wasn't working due to the excel file not being in the "dist" folder.

Regards!

Comment: Nice work!  Quick thought:  Why not store to a simple database like SQLite, rather than Excel?  This will 1) give you (more?) experience with databases and, 2) aid in portability with other programs.  Since Excel in in binary format (as opposed to plain text or database), it makes interaction fiddly.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll check the SQLite idea, I just started programming so I just tried it with Excel because I'm familiar with it.